# How do I dump every byte written to a tty?

Tags: linux, putty, serial-port

When connecting to a switch over serial (`/dev/ttyUSB0`) using PuTTY, I'm presented with a login prompt. If I connect using the Python `pyserial` library and write a few line breaks (`\n\n\n`) I'm not getting anything back from the switch.

However, if I first connect with `pyserial`, then connect with PuTTY, then close PuTTY, I can then read and write bytes using `pyserial` perfectly.

This leads me to believe that PuTTY automatically sends some bytes when it tries to connect that I'm not seeing. How can I spy on what PuTTY writes to `/dev/ttyUSB0` so that I can mimic it from Python?

---

To elaborate, here's what I'm trying to do with Python:

```py
import pyserial

ser = pyserial.serial_for_url("/dev/ttyUSB0")
ser.timeout = 1
ser.write("\n".encode("ASCII"))

print(ser.read(1))   # Times out and returns b""
```

If, after the `serial_for_url` method call, I connect using PuTTY, send a line break (press Enter) in PuTTY, then disconnect, I can then write through `ser` and read the login prompt the switch sends.